# jquery cycle plugin bad display

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have some problem with the cycle plugin.

In firefox it looks good at first time, but if you refresh the page the animation goes over the html table. And works again good if you go in the address bar and and tip enter.

In IE9, it fails on the tab "Location avec chauffeur".

The code i'm using is very simple :

```
$('.animate').cycle({
            fx: 'all', 

        });
```

and in the page something like :

```
<div class="animate">
  <img src="images/1.jpg" width="400" />                   
  <img src="images/2.jpg" width="400" />                   
  <img src="images/3.jpg" width="400" />                   
  <img src="images/4.jpg" width="400" />                   
  <img src="images/5.jpg" width="400" />                   
  <img src="images/6.jpg" width="400" />                   
</div>
```

page : http://www.portatout.net/Pro/Vitrines/Lift-Liege/

PS : I know the HTML is a bit dirty but somebody just ask me to replace GIF animation with something dynamic.

Comment: You have [an HTML validation error that's so serious, the online validator tool fails](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.portatout.net%2FPro%2FVitrines%2FLift-Liege%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  You might be surprised how many cross-browser issues can be fixed with valid HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question it seems like you possibly just want to use the fade animation.  Remove the fx:all part and the plugin will default to only fading in and out your images instead of using different animations that would animate the object over the table.

List of all animations:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/browser.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem (probably causes before by the bad HTML code) :

The cycle() method is called when the images are not all loaded so, some position values are wrong when they are loaded..